# mysql: show which users have permissions to a DB

Tags: mysql, permissions, command-line

Is there a way to show all users that have permissions on a database?

I'm looking for something like:

```
> show_permissions_for_db <DB>;
+----------+----------------------+
| User     | Permissions          |
+----------+----------------------+
| jeff     | read                 |
| jill     | read, write          |
| jack     | read, write, grant   |
+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the Query

```
SELECT
 md.host `Host`,
 md.user `User`,
 md.db `Database`,
 REPLACE(RTRIM(CONCAT(
 IF(md.Select_priv = 'Y', 'Select ', ''),
 IF(md.Insert_priv = 'Y', 'Insert ', ''),
 IF(md.Update_priv = 'Y', 'Update ', ''),
 IF(md.Delete_priv = 'Y', 'Delete ', ''),
 IF(md.Create_priv = 'Y', 'Create ', ''),
 IF(md.Drop_priv = 'Y', 'Drop ', ''),
 IF(md.Grant_priv = 'Y', 'Grant ', ''),
 IF(md.References_priv = 'Y', 'References ', ''),
 IF(md.Index_priv = 'Y', 'Index ', ''),
 IF(md.Alter_priv = 'Y', 'Alter ', ''),
 IF(md.Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y', 'Create_tmp_table ', ''),
 IF(md.Lock_tables_priv = 'Y', 'Lock_tables ', ''),
 IF(md.Create_view_priv = 'Y', 'Create_view ', ''),
 IF(md.Show_view_priv = 'Y', 'Show_view ', ''),
 IF(md.Create_routine_priv = 'Y', 'Create_routine ', ''),
 IF(md.Alter_routine_priv = 'Y', 'Alter_routine ', ''),
 IF(md.Execute_priv = 'Y', 'Execute ', ''),
 IF(md.Event_priv = 'Y', 'Event ', ''),
 IF(md.Trigger_priv = 'Y', 'Trigger ', '')
 )), ' ', ', ') AS `Privileges`
FROM
 mysql.db md WHERE db='DB_NAME';
```

It may give result as you desired.

For Reference have a look at [How to Get a List of Permissions of MySQL Users.](http://blogs.devart.com/dbforge/how-to-get-a-list-of-permissions-of-mysql-users.html)

Comment: Great script Abdul +1.